# Saving file with CGI C program to www directory

Tags: c, apache, cgi, fopen

I have to save a file in the server with a CGI C program and then access it with the client. If I save the file in the cgi-bin directory, it works but I cannot access it with the client because that directory is protected. If I try to save the file in another directory, the fopen function can't create the file.

```
FILE *fh = fopen (filename, "wb");
```

Working but file not accessible.

```
FILE *fh = fopen (//var//www//filename, "wb");
```

Not working. The directory is writeable, it works if I run the statement on a local C program.

So, how I can give permissions to CGI programs to write in the www directory?

I'm using Ubuntu and apache.

Thank you

Comment: if you tried it like this be sure it would not work `FILE *fh = fopen (//var//www//filename, "wb");`.You forgot to add `FILE *fh = fopen ("//var//www//filename", "wb");` maybe that's why, and try to specify the whole path.

Comment: Have you tried `chmod a+rw /var/www`? Default permissions for CGI scripts are: 0755 (rwx-rx-rx), whereas you probably want 0766 (rwx-rw-rw) or something

Answer (score 0):

The permissions were OK. It was a problem in the C code. I solved it using

```
snprintf(pathFile,120,"//var//www//files//%s",filename);
FILE *fh = fopen (pathFile, "wb");
```